# Anngularjs reusing html page for multiple results

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a test app in angular that takes a date input, and displays weather information from an API request for today and tomorrow.

I've used the a dayTemperatures.html using ng-include to show the results for today, but want to reuse dayTemperatures.html to show the weather information for tomorrow on the same page.

I think using ng-include makes it harder. The Brute force want I think think of is to create another view with similar variable names, but that is probably defeating the purpose. Any ideas on how this works?

**Html:**

```
ng-include="'Angular/weatherInfo.html'"
```

**js:**

```
var onWeatherComplete = function (data)
    {
        $scope.dailyWeatherDetails = data;
    }
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: Make a directive for this.

Comment: can u make a jsfiddle for it.

Comment: yes.. creating directive is better, u should do that